# EF Core Custom Relation value

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have a problem with EF, I want a table to have a relationship with another table, but this relationship is conditional on a string being attached to the beginning of the external field of the second table.

What is the problem?
I have a system that is multilingual, they are stored in the main language tables and I have a table that is a translation, in this table there is an ID field to establish a relationship between the tables and the translation table.
In the translation table, the value of the table name and record ID is stored in the interface field.
Like "company-1" this means in the company table ID 1 what is its translation in the target language.

The question is how to define such a relationship in EF Core.

```
public class Translation
{
    [Required]
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("RecordId")]
    public required string RecordId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(20)]
    public string Culture { get; set; } = "";
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string FieldName { get; set; } = "";
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(1024)]
    public string Text { get; set; } = "";

    public virtual Company? Company { get; set; }
}
public class TranslationConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Translation>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Translation> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable("Translation");
        builder.Property(e => e.Id).ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
        builder.HasOne(x => x.Company).WithMany(x => "COMPANY-" + x.Id);
    }
}

public class Company
{
    [Required]
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    
    [ForeignKey("Parent")]
    public int? ParentId { get; set; }
    public CompanyType CompanyType { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(255)]
    public string Caption { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string? CaptionSec { get; set; } 
    [MaxLength(2048)]
    public string? Description { get; set; }
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Translation>? Translations { get; set; }
}
public class CompanyConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Company>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Company> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable("Company");
        builder.Property(e => e.Id).ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
        builder.HasMany(x => x.Contacts).WithOne().HasForeignKey("Id");
        builder.HasMany(x => x.Translations).WithOne().HasForeignKey("COMPANY", "Id");
    }
}
```

How i define
builder.HasMany(x => x.Translations).WithOne().HasForeignKey("COMPANY", "Id");

and

builder.HasOne(x => x.Company).WithMany(x => "COMPANY-" + x.Id);

something like this sql

```
select *,translation.text from company inner join translation on recordid='COMPANY-'+CAST(company.id as nvarchar)
```